# retrieve from database and send to another php file

Tags: php, ajax

I have 2 php files one that retrieve from database, other one take each value came from the database. the problem: data is being sent as whole not row by row. so I can not have each value seperatly. I am trying to find smart way to do so.
first file:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db_name="bbbb";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$data = array(); // create an array
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo $row ['input']; //if my database have 2 rows one with value t1 and other with t2.
}

?>
```

second file:

```
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    retrieveData();

});

   function retrieveData(){
        $.post('quick.php',{}, function(data){

    window.alert(data);

            });

    }


</script>
```

the output i have is a single alert with (t1 t2)
my desire output to be 2 alerts window. first one with value t1 second with value t2.

Comment: So you echo every item. What do you expect?

Comment: if the first row in the database have t1 and the second one have t2. the data i will receive in the retrieveData function will be t1 t2 from alert message. I want the alert message to be 2 times t1 then t2.

Comment: please post the format of data you received and your desired output

Answer (score 0):

try This:
use json to your server side,

```
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo json_encode($row['input']);
}
```

and on your second file:

```
$.post('quick.php',{}, function(data){
    window.alert(data);
},"json");
```